# Proving "each element in a sequence is 0 ==> the element at each index of the sequence is 0" is counterintuitive. How to reason about it?

Tags: dafny

```
lemma blah(p:nat->bool, xs:seq<nat>)
  requires forall t | t in xs :: p(t)
  ensures forall i | 0 <= i < |xs| :: p(xs[i]) {}

lemma zero_is_zero(xs:seq<nat>)
  requires forall x | x in xs :: (x == 0)
  ensures forall k | 0 <= k < |xs| :: (xs[k] == 0) {
  // blah(x => x == 0, xs);
}
```

So, I am trying out dafny version `4.4.0` and am struggling to understand the code-snippet above. It roughly matches one of the two relevant lemmas [here](https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/blob/master/src/Collections/Sequences/Seq.dfy#L93-L111); but I've simplified them a bit.

My understanding is that the `zero_is_zero` lemma is basically a generalization of the `blah` lemma (with the property `p` in this case being `x => x == 0`). So, if anything, it should be *easier* to automatically verify `zero_is_zero`. I was expecting that an element in the sequence would be considered indistinguishable from the same element when accessed through an index.

In practice, it turns out that `blah` is automatically verified (i.e. I don't have do do anything in the lemma body). But for `zero_is_zero` I have to explicitly invoke `blah` to show that it indeed holds for the property `x => x == 0`, and then suddenly it's not a problem anymore.

What is the explanation for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dafny the concept of triggers is important for any existential or forall operator. Here you have specified that `x in xs` as the trigger for a value to be zero. Therefore, you need to invoke that trigger to get the sequence to verify.

```
lemma zero_is_zero(xs:seq<nat>)
  requires forall x | x in xs :: (x == 0)
  ensures forall k | 0 <= k < |xs| :: (xs[k] == 0) 
{
    forall k | 0 <= k < |xs|
        ensures xs[k] == 0
    {
      assert xs[k] in xs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with the concept of trigger earlier; now it looks a lot less confusing.